# How do I run CRON jobs for a Rails app on Amazon EC2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

Could anyone give me a tip how to set up CRON jobs for a Rails app that's running on Amazon EC2 (Ubuntu)?

Trying to find some tutorials or tips how to make it work, but still without any success.
Thank you

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." So, what have you searched through and what have you done to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a model method which execute a task for your crondjob. You can execute the script by using rails runner.

```
rails runner 'User.deliver_reminder_emails!'
```

The whenever gem can even do fancier stuff: https://github.com/javan/whenever

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at `rake` tasks. Check [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Built-In_Rails_Tools/Make_your_own_rake_tasks), [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks) and [this](http://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/custom-rake-task-in-rails/).

Running them is as simple as

```
rake foo:bar
```

You can schedule the same in your `crontab`; You might need to setup the correct `PATH` variable in case you are managing gems locally using `rvm` and `bundler`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out to be rather tricky for me, as the ELB-EC2 instance was trying to run a cron job as root, which seemed to result in a different set of permissions, bundle, etc.

It's a bit hacky, but this worked:

```
 sudo su ec2-user bin/bash -lc "cd /var/app/current && /opt/rubies/ruby-2.1.8/bin/bundle exec/bundle exec rails runner -e your_env \"Model.do_something\""
```

Basically, su to the user that usually runs rails, and explicitly state the paths for bundle.